# Setting title attribute with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find, if I can pass a value on the `title` attribute of a `label` element using Javascript?

I have tried the following Javascript code:

```
function myFunction()
{
    return "Hello!";
}
```

And a piece of HTML code:

```
<label title="myFunction()">TEST</label>
```

But, this isn't working. It just show the 'myFunction()' as a text.

Is it possible, what I am trying to do? If yes, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: You cannot invoke a JS function from the title attribute. What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Hi, I want a random number of labels that are in a template and get generated dynamically to also get dynamicaly using javascript the text to show. This text my differ it is not static

Answer (score 35):

```
<label id='mylabel'>TEST</label>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        return "Hello!";
    }

    document.getElementById('mylabel').setAttribute('title', myFunction());
</script>
```

Should do the job. It first selects the label and then sets the attribute.

Comment: OP wants to set the title using JavaScript, and my code does exactly that. What part of this answer do you think is wrong?

Comment: @KevinBoucher For me it was obvious, what OP is trying to do and _daknøk_'s answer seems to fit perfectly here.

Answer (score 10):

You can't inline javascript like this.

What you may do is

1) give an id to your label and put this at the end of your body

```
<script>
   document.getElementById('myId').title = myFunction();
</script>
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/9L4zN/)

2) if you really want to inline the call, write this at the point where you want your label  :

```
<script>
     document.write('<label title="'+myFunction()+'">TEST</label>');
</script>
```

(this is really not recommended)

Comment: What you describe should result in the same behavior as described by OP.

Comment: @KevinBoucher NO. See demonstration.

Comment: It is true that it would work, but please don't use `document.write`.

Answer (score 7):

Try this way:-

### HTML:

```
<label id="lab">TEST</label>​
```

### JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('lab').setAttribute('title','mytitle');
    alert(document.getElementById('lab').title);
}​
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/Jw3sU/)**

Comment: If i use jquery and have as a selector a certain class instead of the id then I can do to all the label required the text in the title that is needed. Your logic however is what I want to implement in general. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**I got this! If you are using angular you can use this data Binding and call the function**

```
<label title="{{myFunction()}}">TEST</label>
```