# Set title attribute

Tags: javascript

I have a table and use some JS to rewrite some of the contents:

```
var cells1 = document.querySelectorAll('td.listBodyCell');

for (var i = 0; i < cells1.length; i++) {
    cell = cells1[i];
    cell.innerHTML = ConvString(newlinesToBreaks(cell.innerHTML));
    cell.innerHTML = cell.innerHTML.replace(/<br><br>/g, '<br>'); // remove double line breaks
    cell.innerHTML = cell.innerHTML.replace(/With Customer/g, '<span style="color:green;">With Customer</span>');
    cell.innerHTML = cell.innerHTML.replace(/To Investigate/g, '<span style="color:red;">To Investigate</span>');

    if (url_loc.indexOf("CustomCalls") > 0) {
        cell.innerHTML = cell.innerHTML.substring(0,30);
    }
}
```

For this section of the above code:

```
if (url_loc.indexOf("CustomCalls") > 0) {
    cell.innerHTML = cell.innerHTML.substring(0,30);
}
```

I'd like to be able to add a title attribute to the table cell which contains the full cell.innerHTML contents, so that the user can mouse over the cell contents to see their full value.

However, I'm not sure if / how I can achieve that?

I reviewed this SO question:
[Setting title attribute with Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807603/setting-title-attribute-with-javascript-function)

But can't work out how it could be revised to work with my code.

Comment: What’s not working with a simple `cell.title="foo"` then …? Btw. just cutting of HTML content with substring is dangerous, high chance that you create invalid HTML while doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically I just pulled [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12807700/2358222) straight from the question linked in your question...

Just use `.setAttribute();`

So you could use something like:

```
cell.setAttribute('title', cell.innerHTML);
```

Insert this before your if statement though.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can. Just use `setAttribute()`:

```
cell.setAttribute('title', cell.innerHTML);
```

Be sure to do this *before* you truncate `innerHTML` to max 30 chars, else the title will contain the truncated value also.

Comment: possibly use textContent instead of innerHTML if you think there might be html in the selected element